# Mutex definition and use in C

Tags: c, mutex

I am writing a program using C.  I want to have a mutex which can help me to run a new instance of a program in case the first instance of my program lost or stopped working.

I don't know how to start ...
Any help would be really great.

Comment: From the question I'm not quite sure whether you really understand what a mutex is. Could you explain what your program should do in more detail? How should the 2nd instance of the program be started? Is it forked?

Comment: imagine a program like a clock ,which I want to alarm me every 6 min ,I am under Windows , I want the second instance starts working immediately after the first one is stopped working . It is important that one single instance working properly .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, then make a [named mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The first instance to run creates the mutex if it does not yet exists and locks it. Additional instances will fail to get ownership of the mutex using [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and should terminate.

On Unix-like systems, it is typically to write the first instance's [PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) to a lock file. Other instances would then check that file versus the currently running programs. This is a bit more involved and does not utilize mutexes.

---

It seems I misread your question a bit and the prose above addresses the opposite: ensuring that only one instance runs at a time. To restart your process if it hangs or fails is more complicated. I would suggest a program that launches your application and monitors its health externally. The launcher could then start new instances when it detects a problem. The exact process is highly dependent on your platform.

Comment: what is launcher ? I was thinking maybe mutex is a good way, based on my theoric knowledge .

Comment: @Solmaz The launcher is an application you build to manage instances of your program that needs to be monitored and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You create a small loop that starts your program. So it will restart the program if it crashes.

In linux you can do this in a simple bash script

```
$ while true; do ./path/my/prog; done
```

In C, I would guess you write:

```
while(1) {
    system("./path/my/prog");
}
```